# Spamassassin fails after reboot due to missing tmpfiles.d entry

Tags: spamassassin, centos8, reboot

The `/run/spamassassin` directory is not being re-created at boot because there is no `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/spamassassin` file telling it to do so. If I manually create `/run/spamassassin` and start the service everything runs fine, but after reboot, same problem.  The `spamassassin.service` is enabled, so I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do. I'm on version 3.4.2-6.el8.

It looks like it's supposed to be included with the package based on searches on the web, but I can't seem to find the file contents anywhere. When I run `dnf repoquery -l spamassassin` it's not listed as one of the files, so I'm not sure if it's generated after the fact.

Am I supposed to manually create this file; is that file supposed to be generated after install; or is it supposed to be installed as part of the package?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is a lack of any documentation surrounding how to properly set up Spamassassin using unix sockets (`unix:/run/spamassassin/spamd.sock`) instead of the TCP service.  There are precious few mentions here and there of some individual Ubuntu setups, and even fewer for Cent or Fedora, but nothing that I found that addresses the issue of the `/run/spamassassin` directory and it's ephemeral nature.

There is in fact no `tmpfiles.d` file/entry in the package, and to be honest, it never worked for me after I manually tried this method.  I did however find a clue in a long unrelated thread that pointed to a few settings that are missing from the standard `systemd` service unit that solve this problem.

It feels like because the vast majority of people just run spamassassin on separate machines utilizing the TCP stack that there is no need to prepare it for a socket based install, leaving it to be done manually... with no documentation.

The following should be added to an override file at `/etc/systemd/system/spamassassin.service.d/override.conf` within the `[Service]` section.

1. Adding the following lines will have the service create the *runtime* directory each time the service is started if it doesn't exist...

```
RuntimeDirectory=spamassassin
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0770
```

2. These lines will allow the above to be run/created using the `root` user, and then drop down to the `spamd` user and group to run the service. Without these, the above was failing with *permission denied* errors.

```
PermissionsStartOnly=True
User=spamd
Group=spamd
```

Hope this helps those out there struggling with using the socket setup, and not wanting to finally just give in and take the easy route.